# The meaning of the word theory

Tags: philosophy-of-science, truth, idealism, history, rationalism

The normal, day-to-day meaning of the word 'theory' denotes the uncertainty regarding factuality. For instance, when we say that "it is just another theory" what we imply is that there can be many other good enough explanations and this just one of the many possible theories. But in science, the word 'theory' is used to indicate that something has successfully passed many scientific tests and it is not just another theory but it is 'the'' theory and most probably it is the truth (or at least it is a highly believable hypothesis). For instance, theory of evolution. The etymological roots of the word theory is related to the Greek word theoria [which is coming from the word theoros (meaning spectator)] and the roots of the word theory is related to the words such as speculate, contemplate, etc. The roots of the word theory match the ordinary people's day-to-day meaning of the word - not the meaning in which the word theory is used by the scientists. If so, which historical process can explain how the word theory (which lacks any guarantee of being true) got adopted to imply truthfulness in science?

Comment: I think this is a linguistics question, not a philosophy question.

Comment: You are conflating the use of the word theory with its popular general population meaning as opposed to its scientific meaning. The scientific meaning of the word theory is based on the scientific method. Variations of your question have been asked and answered ad nauseam in this forum before.

Comment: A collection of sentences.

Answer (score 1):

A 'theory' is a proposed causal explanation of an event or series of events. Technically speaking we can never 'see' causation; the best we can do is make a more (or sometimes  less) informed guess about the underlying mechanism of causation. That guess is a theory.

Scientists, philosophers, scholars, intellectuals, and the like try to make theories that are *robust*: that seem to be functional across a range of cases and contexts. Regular people aren't quite as concerned with robustness; they are satisfied with theories that seem to make sense, or that conform to some particular narrative. Because scientists are constantly competing with each other to produce robust theories, scientific theories are generally far more functional and far more applicable than lay theories about the same subject. That intrinsic functionality gives scientific theories the countenance of truth. Even though scientific theories are not 'true' per se, they have survived active engagement with numerous attempts to tear them down, replace them, alter them, etc. Lay theories only persist because the passively or actively *avoid* engaging opposition.